# Laravel get object attribute if object id is known

Tags: php, laravel

How do I get the value from a object if the ID is known?

So, I got the house id, in the house model there is an user_id for every house like:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use stdClass;
use App\Service\ChangesetService;

class HouseProfile extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id', 'user_id'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Every user got an address (string)

I need the address and I got the house id and I'm working in a blade file in Laravel 5.5

Comment: your question is not clear. please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly:

```
@if($house->user)
 {{ $house->user->address }}
@endif
```

Comment: But how do I get the $house if I only got the house id? something like 'gethouseforid(id)'?

Comment: @belgiums I think it is not a good practice, but you can get it so {{ \App\HouseProfile::find($houseId)->user->address }}

Answer (score 0):

You should *never* run queries of put too much logic in you Blade files. Instead you should pass variables to them.

In your controller

```
$house = HouseProfile::findOrFail($houseId);
return view('your.view.name', [
    'house' => $house
]);
```

In your blade file you can use @IndianCoding response, so

```
@if($house->user)
 {{ $house->user->address }}
@endif
```